# Declaring a variable on element, showing it on view (unrecognized variable)

Tags: variables, cakephp, view, element

I have an element called 'init' and a view (CAKEPHP)
I'm declaring variables on 'init' like this:

```
<?
$auxUrl = Router::url(array("controller"=>"Uploader","action"=>"admin_index"));
$uploaderLink = '<a href=' . $auxUrl . '?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100% rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]">r</a>';
?>
```

then in View I do:

```
<?
  echo $this->element('init');
  echo $uploaderLink;
?>
```

and it says that it doesn't recognize the echoed variable...

I'm obviously doing something very wrong, but what it is??

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you are doing in your element is declaring a few variables, you should be doing this in the controller and using `$this->set` to pass the variables to the view.